# Wordpress Custom Field Suite & wp_insert_post

Tags: wordpress

```php
$post_data = [
    'post_type' => 'messages',
    'post_title'    => $_POST['subject'],
    'post_content'  => $_POST['message'],
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'meta_input'     => [
        '???' => $_POST['name'],
        '???' => $_POST['email']
    ]
];

$post_id = wp_insert_post(wp_slash($post_data));
```

I'm using Custom Field Suite plugin to create custom fields. What should I use instead of ???

Comment: You can use ACF (Advanced Custom Fields Pro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

```php
$post_data = [
    'post_type' => 'messages',
    'post_title'    => $_POST['subject'],
    'post_content'  => $_POST['message'],
    'post_status'   => 'publish'
];

$post_id = wp_insert_post(wp_slash($post_data));

CFS()->save([
    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'email' => $_POST['email']
], [
    'ID' => $post_id
]);
```

More information in the [docs](http://customfieldsuite.com/api/save.html)